# how to do this calculation in sql query. i have to combine the same product

Tags: php, mysql

> Here is my query

```
SELECT
`product_id`,
`product_quantity`,
`product_price`,
`product_price` * `product_quantity` AS `product_total`,
`purch_price`,
`purch_price` * `product_quantity` AS `purch_total`
FROM
`master_stock`
WHERE `product_id`='SSK-SQ2001-20W-6500K'
GROUP BY
`id`
ORDER BY
`id`
```

> Here is the table
>
> **product_id** **product_quantity** **product_price** **product_total** **purch_price** **purch_total**
>
> SQ2001   100       167      1670     134     13400
>
> SQ2001   100       167      1670     135     13500

> Now i want to get the result like this (Because it has same id but purchase price is different )
>
> **product_id**          **product_quantity**  **product_total**  **purch_total**
>
> SQ2001           200        334000      26900

> What i try but could not able to get result

```
SELECT
ms.id,
ms.product_id,
ms.product_name,
sum(ms.product_quantity) AS total_quantity,
ms.product_price*ms.product_quantity AS product_total,
ms.purch_price*ms.product_quantity AS purch_total
FROM
master_stock ms
GROUP BY
ms.product_id
ORDER BY
ms.product_id;
```

[here is my result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f16ce/45)

> Please help Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you elaborate as to which columns of your resultset are not displaying what you want them to? And please add the desired result, too. That would make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @RogerKreft sir `product_total` and `purch_total`

Comment: have you tried this: ...
    ms.product_price * sum(ms.product_quantity) AS product_total,
    ms.purch_price * sum(ms.product_quantity) AS purch_total
FROM ...

Comment: sir it's through me an error
**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'FROM master_stock ms GROUP BY ms.product_id ORDER BY ms.product_id'` at line 10**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you problem correctly you need to sum up the quantity before multiplying it with the prices. Otherwise you just multiply it with one of the quantities. Here would be the solution to that problem:

```sql
SELECT
    ms.id,
    ms.product_id,
    ms.product_name,
    sum(ms.product_quantity) AS total_quantity,
    sum(ms.product_price*ms.product_quantity) AS product_total,
    sum(ms.purch_price*ms.product_quantity) AS purch_total
FROM
    master_stock ms
GROUP BY
    ms.product_id
ORDER BY
    ms.product_id;
```

fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f16ce/49/0

Comment: This code-only answer is missing its educational explanation.

Comment: @mickmackusa: you are right. i added an explanation.

Comment: @RogerKreft hello sir in `purch_total` it should be `26900` but in your query it's `26800`

Answer (score 1):

> we have to multiply before sum

```
SELECT
  ms.id,
  ms.product_id,
  ms.product_name,
  ms.purch_gst,
  ms.gst,
  SUM(ms.product_price * ms.product_quantity) AS product_total,
  SUM(ms.purch_price * ms.product_quantity) AS purch_total,
  SUM(ms.product_quantity) AS total_quantity
FROM
  master_stock ms
GROUP BY
  ms.product_id
ORDER BY
  ms.product_id
```